# CUDADot (CUDA) taking longer than indicated by //AbsoluteTiming (~500x)

Tags: performance-tuning, cudalink, cuda

I'm using MMA 13.3 with a fresh install of cuda toolkit version 12.2. CUDADot is not as fast as indicated by absolute timing.

Running the commands found here

(https://reference.wolfram.com/language/CUDALink/tutorial/Functions.html#101237416)

for comparing performance of CUDAdot[] and dot[], the output is similar, but the actual time it takes for my computer to finish computing is about 500 times longer than the indicated timing.

The built-in dot product takes slightly longer than the indicated value, and if I use CUDAMemoryLoad, it shows a similar time differnce. However, the actual computation time increases to almost twice the time of using the cpu.

The time it takes to take the dot product on the CPU, GPU, and memoryLoad GPU is 4, 15 and 7 seconds respectively.

Using a Ryzen 5900x and a GTX1080. CUDAQ[] returns true and everything seems to load fine.

[image]

Comment: I cannot tell why `AbsoluteTiming` shows timings that are so different from the actual wall-clock timings. But with regard to the GPU being slower than the CPU here: The GPU is reported to have a theoretical peak performance of 277.3 GFLOPS in _double precision_, see [here](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-gtx-1080.c2839). (Note that the _single precisions_ is 32 times as high is it is not unsual for gaming cards.)

Comment: I could not find precise numbers for the CPU, but it seems to have a _single precision_ throughput of about 900 GFLOPS (see here https://gadgetversus.com/processor/amd-ryzen-9-5900x-gflops-performance/). The ratio  between single precision and double precision performance on CPUs is typically 2:1, so I expect that the _double precision_ performance is about 450 GFLOPS which fits quite well with wall clock timings that you obtained.